# Check passed type interface

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have the following interfaces:

```
struct Base {};

struct Renderable {};
struct Updateable {};
```

Classes use it like this:

```
class Foo1 : Base {};
class Foo2 : Base, Renderable {};
class Foo3 : Base, Renderable, Updateable {};
```

There is a function which accepts objects of these types:

```
template <typename T>
void add(T* obj)
{
   // Object inherits Renderable interface
   if (static_cast<Renderable*>(obj))
      ...

   // Object inherits Updateable interface
   if (static_cast<Updateable*>(obj))
      ...
}
```

And this does not work when I pass object of type `Foo1`. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Can you use `dynamic_cast` (i.e. are your types polymorphic?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static_cast<T>()` does not check the runtime type information; `dynamic_cast<T>()` does. You need to replace `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast`, and enable run-time type information ([RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)) when you compile your code if your compiler has it off by default. You need to make sure that `Base` has at least one virtual function.

Note that generally this is not a very robust design, because your `add()` function may break when you add another type to your hierarchy. A better approach would be to implement [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in the `Base` and the code that does the `add`.

Here is how you can do it:

```
struct Visitor {
    virtual void visitFoo1(Foo1 &foo1);
    virtual void visitFoo2(Foo2 &foo2);
    virtual void visitFoo3(Foo3 &foo3);
};
struct Base {
    virtual void accept(visitor& v);
    ...
};
struct Foo1 : public Base {
    virtual void accept(visitor& v) {
        visitFoo1(*this);
    }
    ...
};
struct Foo2 : public Base {
    virtual void accept(visitor& v) {
        visitFoo2(*this);
    }
    ...
};
struct Foo3 : public Base {
    virtual void accept(visitor& v) {
        visitFoo3(*this);
    }
    ...
};
```

Now the code that has the `add` function can do this:

```
struct FooProcessor : public visitor {
    virtual void visitFoo1(Foo1 &foo1) {
        ...
    }
    virtual void visitFoo2(Foo2 &foo2) {
        ...
    }
    virtual void visitFoo3(Foo3 &foo3) {
        ...
    }
    void add(Base &b) {
        b.accept(*this);
    }

}
```

When you call `accept` on the instance of `Base`, it calls back one of the `visitFooN` functions, making RTTI unnecessary.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` always return nullptr. For example: `add(Foo3)`.

Comment: Isn't there a a way to do the subtype check at compile time? That would avoid the type info crawling and (if it's not needed for other reasons) `virtual` and RTTI altogether.

Comment: @Ockonal Please see the edit (the `Base` needs to have at least one `virtual` function in order for RTTI to work).